# How was this specific chart created in Power BI?

Tags: charts, powerbi, business-intelligence, powerbi-desktop

I am using `Power BI` for my business intelligence reports and I came across this nice chart in a Power BI Report.

[image: Chart]

Unfortunately, the author did not provide any information on the type of chart used (or how he created it). I have tried searching for the chart in the `Custom Visuals` gallery of `Power BI` ([Custom Visuals](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/samples/)) but could not find any chart which was a close match to it.

Any information or links on how to create it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example chart is a [Ribbon chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-ribbon-charts) and is not custom visual, but is a standard visual in Power BI from about the May 2019 release.

[image: Power BI Visualizations Oct 2019]

An example file on how to use it is [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/6/D/96DDC2FF-2568-491D-AAFA-AFDD6F763AE3/Retail%20Analysis%20Sample%20PBIX.pbix)